# Amailut (trying hard/ toiling) to learn Torah

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, torah-study

What's the source for amailut (trying hard/ toiling) to learn Torah? Is there any benefit to try learning Torah on your own without help, when you can learn Torah through asking others and looking things up (which is a much faster route)?

Comment: מועדים לשמחה and welcome to Mi Yodeya! Regarding your interesting question, consider that hard work does not imply inefficient work (which might itself be considered a form of *bitul Torah*). If you work efficiently and with others, there will still be plenty of Torah left for you to learn and you will also be able to study your topic at a higher level. Further, the Talmud is replete with exhortations for people to study together with others. That said, see *B'rachos* 63b regarding hard work:כתתו עצמכם על דברי תורה כדאמר ריש לקיש... אין דברי תורה מתקיימין אלא במי שממית עצמו עליה.

Comment: Along the lines of @Fred's comment, consider that, with the help of others your hard work can yield better results.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26606/759

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/82589

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/82645

Answer (score 4):

You can work hard and ask others for help.

> Once the Alter Rebbe called the
>   Tzemach Tzedek
>   and offered to grant him a gift – a blessing for
>   an understanding of Torah. The
>   Tzemach Tzedek
>   declined the offer, saying that he wanted to
>   acquire Torah through toil. He later regretted
>   this, for whatever levels of Torah he could have
>   received as a gift from the Alter Rebbe, there
>   would always be additional levels to toil for.

For more information about toiling while learning Torah, see
http://www.lmaanyishmeu.com/pdf/195%20-%20Toiling%20in%20Torah%20-2.pdf

Comment: I know it is different, but that story reminds me of the one told about R Elyashiv here http://www.ravaviner.com/2013/06/shut-sms-213.html

Answer (score 0):

Pirkei avos 5:25,26

Ben Bag Bag says: "turn in it, turn in it for everything is in it. Reflect in it, grow old in it, don't turn from it for there is no greater measure than it".

Ben Hai Hai says: "according to the toil is the reward".

You can never learn enough. And the more energy you put in to understanding and exploring torah, the more rewarding the experience will be.

I doubt that these Rabbis encouraged learning only on one's own. That contradicts a main theme of the mesorah, outlined throughout Pirkei Avos. Learn from others when you can ("Make for yourself a rav", ibid 1:6, "Who is wise, one who learns from every man" 4:1, "have your house be a place for sages, sit in the dust of their feet drink their words with thirst" 1:4). Think over what they say, toil in it. When you cant learn from others, learn still and work to understand torah.

Learn however you can, as much as you can is the message, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The Gemara in Brachos 6b says "Agra Dishmita Svara"- The reward for learning is in "svara"=reasoning meaning the greatest type of limud hatorah in schar wise in merit in learning something that is more intellectually challenging.

as for the second half of the question, generally you will get better understanding when learning with a group than by yourself. this is true for most disciplines, secular or religious.