# Jacob Neusner's talmud bavli and yerushalmi

Tags: talmud-gemara, jewish-books, translation, english

How does Jacob Neusner's translations of the talmud bavli and yerushalmi compare to artscroll's, koren's, and soncino's?

I have never seen Neusner's in a shul or bais midrash unlike the other three mentioned; is there a reason for that? Is it an accurate translation?

Answer (score 11):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Neusner). As described there, Neusner has been criticized by the following scholars in his field of study:

> [Shaye J. D. Cohen, "Jacob Neusner, Mishnah and Counter-Rabbinics,"
>   Conservative Judaism, Vol.37(1) Fall 1983 p. 48-63]
>
> [Craig A. Evans, "Mishna and Messiah 'In Context'," Journal of
>   Biblical Literature, (JBL), 112/2 1993, p. 267-289]
>
> [Saul Lieberman, "A Tragedy or a Comedy" Journal of the American
>   Oriental Society, Vol.104(2) April/June 1984 p. 315-319]
>
> [Hyam Maccoby, "Jacob Neusner's Mishnah," Midstream, 30/5 May 1984 p.
>   24-32]
>
> [Hyam Maccoby, "Neusner and the Red Cow," Journal for the Study of
>   Judaism (JSJ), 21 1990, p. 60-75]
>
> [John C. Poirier, "Jacob Neusner, the Mishnah and Ventriloquism," The
>   Jewish Quarterly Review, LXXXVII Nos.1-2, July–October 1996, p. 61-78]
>
> [E.P.Sanders, Jewish Law from Jesus to the Mishnah. Philadelphia,
>   1990.]
>
> [Solomon Zeitlin, "A Life of Yohanan ben Zakkai. A Specimen of Modern
>   Jewish Scholarship," Jewish Quarterly Review, 62, 1972, p. 145-155.]
>
> [Solomon Zeitlin, "Spurious Interpretations of Rabbinic Sources in the
>   Studies of the Pharisees and Pharisaim," Jewish Quarterly Review, 62,
>   1974, p. 122-135.]
>
> [ Evan M. Zuesse, "The Rabbinic Treatment of 'Others' (Criminals,
>   Gentiles) according to Jacob Neusner," Review of Rabbinic Judaism,
>   Vol. VII, 2004, p. 191-229]
>
> [Evan M. Zuesse, "Phenomenology of Judaism," in: Encyclopaedia of
>   Judaism, ed. J. Neusner, A. Avery-Peck, and W.S. Green, 2nd Edition
>   Leiden: Brill, 2005 Vol.III, p. 1968-1986. (Offers an alternative to
>   Neusner's theory of "Judaisms.")]
>
> Some scholars are critical of Neusner's methodology, and assert that
>   many of his arguments are circular or attempt to prove "negative
>   assumptions" from a lack of evidence. Others are critical of Neusner's
>   reading and interpretations of Rabbinic texts, finding that his
>   account is forced and inaccurate.
>
> Some scholars have questioned Neusner's grasp of Rabbinic Hebrew and
>   Aramaic. Probably the most famous and biting criticism came from Saul
>   Lieberman: about Neusner's translation of the Jerusalem Talmud,
>   Lieberman wrote:"...one begins to doubt the credibility of the
>   translator [Neusner]. **And indeed after a superficial perusal of the
>   translation, the reader is stunned by [Neusner's] ignorance of
>   Rabbinic Hebrew, of Aramaic grammar, and above all of the subject
>   matter with which he deals." He ended his review: "I conclude with a
>   clear conscience: The right place for [Neusner's] English translation
>   is the waste basket.** "[Saul Lieberman, "A Tragedy or a Comedy" Journal
>   of the American Oriental Society, Vol.104(2) April/June 1984 p.
>   315-319]

Comment: Partial answer more questions unanswered.

Comment: Indeed Lieberman's piece is notoriously quite sharp.

Comment: anyone ever read Haym Soltoveitchik's review on one of Neusner's student's book? Probably one of the funniest Rabbinic pieces I have ever read.

Comment: Ok Ephraim I found it; --
Review: Responsa: Literary History and Basic Literacy
Author(s): Haym Soloveitchik
Review by: Haym Soloveitchik
Source: AJS Review, Vol. 24, No. 2 (1999), pp. 343-357
Published by: Cambridge University Press on behalf of the Association for Jewish Studies
Stable URL: http://www.jstor.org/stable/1486759

Comment: @sam: If you have multiple related questions, and you want each one answered in full, it might help to make each one be a separate post. I do admit that this is a slight hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Neusner only translates the historical document as it was codified ca. 500 CE.  He does not include any later commentaries such as Rashi, nor any halakhic literature.

Comment: Neither did Soncino...