# What did the haircut of Ben Elasha look like?

Tags: maseches-sanhedrin, haircuts, kohen-gadol

The Gemara in [Sanhedrin 22b](http://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.22b.1-86?lang=en) states:

(*Source from [Sefaria.org](http://www.sefaria.org)*)

> *:שאלו את רבי איזהו תספורת של כ"ג אמר להן צאו וראו מתספורת של בן אלעשה*
>
> *They asked Rebbe "What is the haircut of the Kohen Gadol?" He said to them "Go and see the haircut of Ben Elasha"*

Is there any visual examples available of what this looked like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ShamanSTK](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/9629/shamanstk) showed me the following from the [Hebrew Stiensaltz Talmud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Talmud:_The_Steinsaltz_Edition)[image: 1]]

which claims that it is a Machlokes Rishonim of what it actually looked like. **That being said I would like to verify if what is written here with sources cited.** Which are not present here<sup>1</sup>. But still insightful nevertheless!

<sup>1<sub>It is to be noted that my concern stems from a compelling critique by [Rav Aharon Feldman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharon_Feldman) in his book ["Eye of the Storm"](https://www.amazon.ca/Eye-Storm-Calm-Raging-Issues/dp/1598264540) about the problems with the Stiensaltz Talmud (original article is [here](http://traditionarchive.org/news/originals/Volume%2025/No.%204/Learning%20Gemara%20In.pdf)). I'm not saying that there are any problems with this source in particular, however I am looking to verify the sources claimed.</sub></sup>

Comment: Be sure to read responses before calling it compelling http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/40785/759